# Why my Function Has no Output Plot?

Tags: plotting, functions

Below is my commands on a mathematica script to plot a function. In order to see why the function has issue to be plotted, I have tried to plot the intermediate functions one-by-one. It seems that my line 4 (and/or possibly line 2) is problematic. What am I missing for the plot? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
yfunc[M_] := (M /(10^12));

sigmafunc[M_] := (16.9*(yfunc[M])^0.41)/(
  1 + 1.102*(yfunc[M])^0.20 + 6.22*(yfunc[M])^0.333);

xfunc[M_] := 1.686/sigmafunc[M];

Remove[dsigmadM]; dsigmadM[M_] := (Log[10]*10^M)^-1*D[sigmafunc[x], x] //. x -> M;

funcsigma[M_] := 
  0.322*Sqrt[(2*0.707)/\[Pi]]*(1 + (0.707*(xfunc[M])^2)^-0.3)*
   xfunc[M]*Exp[-((0.707*(xfunc[M])^2)/2)];

dndLogM[M_] := -0.05152*10^12*funcsigma[M]/sigmafunc[M]*dsigmadM[M];

LogLogPlot[dsigmadM, {M, 10^8, 10^16}, PlotRange -> {10^(-10), 10}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Try `LogPlot[dsigmadM[M], {M, 7, 17}, PlotRange -> {0.0001, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic]` and report back.

Comment: I have tried that too. It still doesn't work!

Comment: Ah, then do this: `Remove[dsigmadM]; dsigmadM[M_] := (Log[10]*10^M)^-1*sigmafunc'[M];`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Dear J.M., what did you actually changed in that differentiation line? What does " ' " mean after sigmafunc?

Comment: Did you try clearing/removing `dsigmadM[]` (actually all your symbols) before executing that definition?

Comment: Yes. No success.

Comment: Maybe start over in a fresh session; if it still doesn't work, then I can make suggestions.

Comment: I have tried that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the plot command (as pointed out by J.M.), you also have a problem with the derivative. Here's one way to fix it:

```
yfunc[M_] := 10^(12 - M);

sigmafunc[
   M_] := (16.9*(yfunc[M])^0.41)/(1 + 1.102*(yfunc[M])^0.20 + 
     6.22*(yfunc[M])^0.333);

xfunc[M_] := 1.686/sigmafunc[M];

dsigmadM[M_] := (Log[10]*10^M)^(-1)*D[sigmafunc[x], x] //. x -> M;

funcsigma[M_] := 
  0.322*Sqrt[(2*0.707)/π]*(1 + (0.707*(xfunc[M])^2)^-0.3)*
   xfunc[M]*Exp[-((0.707*(xfunc[M])^2)/2)];

dndLogM[M_] := 0.05152*funcsigma[M]/sigmafunc[M]*dsigmadM[M];

Plot[dsigmadM[M], {M, 7, 17}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi bill, thanks for the advice. It seems that I cannot get LogPlot though. It's weird.

Comment: The argument of the logarithms is supposed to be positive so that they have legitimate logarithm. Besides LogPlot, I cannot even get the Plot.

Comment: The reason you can't get `LogPlot` is because the function takes on negative values.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I had an inconsistency in the definition of one of my intermediate (namely first) function in the script. I had a "-" typo which had resulted in undefined values. However, the main issue was that I should have compensated the factor $10^{12}$ which I had introduced (in a wrong manner) in the first equation. This is now edited as can be seen from the very last definition just before plotting command. But, even if I had those correctly typed, yet I noticed that the comment made by Bill is significant. Thanks for everyone's help.